# How to move mysql database and mysql server to another machine

Tags: ubuntu, backup, mysql, database

I am having Ubuntu 14.04 desktop in which i develop software. Due to some reasons my hard disk has developed many bad sectors. I want to move my mysql server software and all the databases to a new machine. How should i do it? Somebody please help me.

Comment: You can use mysqldump.

Comment: I wish to move the mysql software along with the settings so that i dont have to configure it in my new machine again.

Comment: There are not so many config files, check your current setup for example I think in Ubuntu /etc/mysql/my.cnf or whatever your current mysql uses. If on your new server you use the same Ubuntu, mysql version should be the same

Comment: You can use mysqldump or if it will fail - use binary logs to restore from them

Comment: I have done this using mysqldump. Other things to remember on the new install is to implement any changes to *my.cnf* (usually in */etc/mysql*) such as a different logfile size (I needed this to work with BLObs). There may be other changes if you were not using the default *datadir*.

Answer (score 2):

Easiest way is probably to install Ubuntu 14.04 on the new system including mysql-server packages you already have installed on the old system; use `dpkg -l mysql\*` to show what those packages are (make your terminal wide enough first to not truncate columns). Ensure the new system has the same or newer versions (*not* older versions).

Now stop mysql on old and new systems. You can now copy over the `/var/lib/mysql` directory including contents; I usually use rsync for that:

```
# rsync -ai /var/lib/mysql/ newsystem:/var/lib/mysql/
```

You can also use `tar` to collect all the files first and copy the tarfile, as getting `rsync` to work with root might be a bit of a challenge:

```
# cd /var/lib; tar cvf /var/tmp/mysql-files.tar mysql/
# scp /var/tmp/mysql-files.tar newsystem:/var/tmp
```

On new system:

```
# cd /var/lib; mv mysql mysql.orig
# tar xvf /var/tmp/mysql-files.tar
```

You may want to copy `/etc/mysql/` including contents in the same way.

Now start mysql again and everything should work.